# Can question timeline be available for deleted questions for 10k+ users?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-questions, 10k-tools, timeline

For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757210) question's timeline is 404 for 10k users, who are supposed to be able to see deleted posts.

> https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2757210/timeline

So, can we 10k+ users be able to see deleted questions' [timelines](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2757210/timeline) like we can on [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2757210/revisions)?

Comment: Isn't this feature still experimental for everyone?

Comment: FYI, all the links you posted in your question are broken.

Comment: @Evan, it's not broken for 10k+ users, but timeline is currently broken, so I am requesting it.

Comment: I just tried viewing a timeline of a deleted question on Meta (I only have 10k here), and I get a page not found. Is this the same thing you get on SO? Or does it show the page with incorrect output?

Comment: Yes @Jon, same here, but for being 10k+ users, I think we should able to see it like question page and revisions.

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree. I was just making sure I was reproducing the problem properly.

Comment: @Jon, could you post that as answer? then I can award bounty. :-)

Comment: Until Jeff implements this, am I going to keep getting all the bounties? LOL

Comment: @Jon, yes, I am thinking to do so. Now, I am seeing another +50 button under +100 div :-) But sorry for small amounts, my aim was just to get some attention.

Comment: Yeah, I was joking; I know the bounty is just to get attention. Although it may be the first post in the system to receive a second bounty (bug hunting time!).

Comment: Why was this status-completed by Jeff on Aug 18 '10?  Or has it recently broken again?

Comment: @Richard, I wasn't active (or I don't remember) at that time Jeff tagged as status-completed, so I am not sure this is recent case or not.

Comment: @Shog9, Thanks for the retag, and btw, I am seeing 2 responses for your edit with same content - http://i.imgur.com/dl4GN.png - Is it supposed to be correct?

Comment: I have no idea what that's about, @YOU

Comment: @Shog9, I mean [revisions-list](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/51542/revisions) shows there is only one edit by you, but activity msg (response) on my profile says 2 revisions, So I am wondering that could be a bug.

Comment: Yeah... @YOU should report that... ;-)

Comment: @Shog9, sure :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This just kinda happened when we released the new timeline. Kind of. What happened is we [didn't have any permissions on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273600/new-timeline-enables-anyone-to-see-any-deleted-post-without-checking-their-privi) at all when it was initially released. That's been corrected so it only shows to 10k users.

Enjoy seeing your timelines.

Answer (score 15):

Given that 10k users can see the revisions list of deleted posts, I think it's reasonable to be able to see the timeline view of a deleted question.

Part of the issue right now is that the full history is not available in the timeline view. For example, if you look at this post here: [revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/54472/revisions) [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/54472/timeline), you can see that events related to deletion/undeletion do not appear in the timeline (close/reopen events are shown -- [example with both a close and reopen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/53595/timeline)).

Jeff has said that he plans to have the timeline view publicly available at some point. I assume the dev team is still working on this, although I'm not sure why the entire page is blocked when the view of a deleted question is requested.

Comment: A 'synopsis' would be nice when a question gets hot. +1

Comment: just wanted to test second bounty :P

Comment: @S.Mark: Interesting. Looks like they get grouped together, instead of being separated (in the tooltip as well). I'm really curious how this information will show up in the data dump. (I pray it's not collapsed into a single bounty award vote.)

Comment: How does your reputation report identify the multi-bounty?

Comment: Ah yes, good idea. It's separated into two BountyClose votes, so presumably that same information will show up in the data dump. I guess it's just collapsed on the UI side of things. @Gra

Comment: Makes some sense. Would be nicer if the tooltip at least stated how many bounties a single answer received (lest we get questions on how someone seems to have earned 1000 points in bounty for one answer), but I can understand collapsing the UI. Imagine the mess a stacked view would be if one answer was fed dozens of bounties by the adoring masses.

Comment: The tooltip could have it expanded. "This answer has been awarded bounties worth 100, and 50 reputation" or "This answer has been awarded 2 bounties worth a total of 150 reputation." @Gra

Comment: I like the latter one. Ima make a feature request.

Comment: Sounds good. @Gra

Comment: I forgot to award bounty, setting another one.

Comment: @S.Mark: Oddly enough, the system auto-awarded half the bounty amount.

Comment: @S.Mark: To net out the bounties you're giving me, I'm going to set up a bounty on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51947/allow-users-to-opt-out-of-all-favorite-notifications) and award to you (that question could use more exposure anyway).

Comment: One possible explanation for the bounty auto-award is that instead of properly tracking new answers after the assignment of the bounty, it specifically tracks new answers after the *first* bounty was assigned. So until someone posts a better answer, yours will continue to receive auto-rewards. Whether this applies to bounties from just the one user, or if it affects all bounties on a question... honestly I wouldn't mind spending 50 reputation just to test it.

Comment: ah @grace, I have reassigned the bounty without noticing that you like  to test. you may try next week.

Comment: @grace, you may try now, if you want to test that.

Comment: @grace: The bounty expired and was auto-awarded to this answer.

Comment: @Jon Looks like my hypothesis was correct. Posted [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58348/bounty-auto-award-only-cares-about-when-the-first-bounty-was-posted).