# Community user - Bounty reputation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties, community-user

[Mr. Community♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=summary)'s profile occasionally shows negative reputation for bounties.
However, I cannot find any link or reason for the negative reputation. The [Bounty tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=bounties) does not show any relevant activity either<sup>I can see deleted posts as well.</sup>.

**Question**: What is the cause of the negative reputation change, marked as **`Bounty`** at the [reputation tab?

[image: Reputation tab]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=reputation)

### Section 2: Feature request

Community♦ also owns [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=revisions) by anonymous users. The author may not know about the community user, and This feature is not mentioned at his profile.

**Suggestion: Extend Community's profile:**
  •   Add another list item: *`Own edits of unregistered users.`*
  •   Add a link to the meta question: *FAQ: [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)*.

### Related posts

- [Why is the Community user accepting answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62557/why-is-the-community-user-accepting-answers) (Jeffs great answer does not explain the reputation mutations, unfortunately)
- FAQ: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)
- FAQ: [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)
- [Eeeek! "Community" user got sudden rep boost.. how come?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77115/eeeek-community-user-got-sudden-rep-boost-how-come)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The -500 on Nov 28 is due to the +500 bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492080/styling-the-text-outline-in-qts-tabs), as you can see in the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7492080/revisions) it was started in the same time of the -500 in the profile. (Reputation is reduced when the bounty is started, not awarded)

It was most probably started by the question author who had his account deleted for some reason thus removing the bounty "reference" to the community user.

The missing link to the relevant question is either a bug, or by design only dev can answer this for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And `-100` is caused by [this bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7379729/revisions). Do you know whether or not the bounty reassignment affect Community♦'s reputation?

Comment: No problem.. I think it does affect the reputation but in general the reputation of that account is volatile thing, for all I know maybe the developers are messing with it manually sometimes for their own tests. :)