# 500 Internal Server Error on revisions link of certain answer

Tags: status-completed, revisions-list, bug

500 Internal Server Error on [revisions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/54888/revisions) of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51542/can-question-timeline-be-available-for-deleted-questions-for-10k-users/54888#54888)

Comment: As an aside: the revisions are shown when expanding them in [the question's timeline](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/51542/timeline). And the comments in the error page show "Actual error: Sequence contains no elements", but I guess only the developers know what to do with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was due to some bad data in our votes table.  It will be fixed automatically from now on.