# Question timeline returns 404 for deleted questions, even though I can see them

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, timeline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can question timeline be available for deleted questions for 10k+ users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51542/can-question-timeline-be-available-for-deleted-questions-for-10k-users)

The [timeline feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/119911/timeline) that shows a condensed view of a questions's life doesn't work for deleted questions — it shows a "Page Not Found" error.

This is despite the fact that I have 10k reputation and can see the question itself.