# Timeline not working on deleted questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, 10k-tools, timeline

Over on Programmers, we had a troll [roll through](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/213819/why-is-programming-code-so-hard-how-do-you-remember-what-to-write-and-stuff).  I tried taking a look at [that Q's timeline](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/213819/timeline) but received a 404 not-found.  I'm a 10k+ user there, so I can see deleted questions and thought I was supposed to be able to see timelines for deleted questions.

This [MSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119911/question-timeline-returns-404-for-deleted-questions-even-though-i-can-see-them) was asked in 2012 and was closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51542/can-question-timeline-be-available-for-deleted-questions-for-10k-users) from 2010:
with the implied answer of "yes, 10k users can see deleted question timelines."

But the 2010 question doesn't have a resolution to it, and it's not clear what the resolution should be.  Looking in the [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/51542/revisions), the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) has been removed along with a comment indicating the functionality may have never worked even though other comments indicate it *should have* worked.

***My question*** - Should I be able to see the timeline on deleted questions or is the current timeline functionality (still) broken?  Or did something magical happen because that question was closed and deleted so quickly?

Comment: Where in that question does it imply that you *can* see the timeline for a deleted question? It's a feature request to be able to have access to it.

Comment: @animuson - implied by a line in Jon's answer.  "Jeff has said that he plans to have the timeline view publicly available at some point."  I'm not positive that I _should_ be able to see it, which is part of the basis of my question.

Comment: No, you can't. The feature hasn't been implemented yet. I'm honestly not sure why the status-completed tag was ever added there, but as far as I know this has never worked. They're arguing there that yes, you *should* be able to see it, but that doesn't imply that you can.

Comment: @animuson - ok, sounds like the answer then is "No, you shouldn't see it" and "No that aspect of the timeline functionality isn't broken because it hasn't been written."

Comment: You're using the wrong word - no, you *can't* see it. The system currently prevents you from loading the timeline on a deleted question. As far as whether it's broken, that depends on your definition of broken. I'd consider that entire timeline broken, but I also have access to the fancy moderator's timeline which makes that one look like the leftovers you'd feed to the stray dog that keeps showing up to your house.

Comment: @animuson - now you're just teasing me by mentioning the mod view of the timeline.  So. not. fair.  :-)  And I don't mean to play semantics with can't / shouldn't.  They both boil down to "no soup for me."

Comment: No timeline for deleted questions and there never was such. Jeff tagged LOTS of stuff, probably mistake or misguided information he got from devs at some point. I've bumped that old request.