# Accepted answers to deleted questions don't have a checkmark

Tags: bug, accepted-answer, deleted-questions

It seems that when an answer is implicitly deleted along with the parent question, it loses its checkmark. This, coupled with the fact that [the timeline view is broken for deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51542/can-question-timeline-be-available-for-deleted-questions-for-10k-users), makes it impossible to tell what the accepted answer to a deleted question used to be.

If, on the other hand, only the accepted answer is deleted, it retains the checkmark.

I recently had an [old question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24591) deleted, and neither the +2 rep to me or the +15 rep to the [answerer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/10450/kyubey?tab=reputation) (9 upvotes + accept) were revoked, so it looks like the answer is still technically accepted.

The public data dump (literally from the day before it was deleted) <s>confirms</s> used to confirm that I had accepted an answer. Yet [here it is, without checkmark and all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIPQg.png).

Comment: Do you have a link to such a deleted question, lacking the checkmark on the accepted answer? I don't believe I've seen this.

Comment: [Counterexample (implicitly deleted answer showing checkmark)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498698/white-light-vs-black-dark-backgrounds-health-effects).

Comment: @CodyGray [Yes](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24591), but most people here won't be able to see it because it's not on SO.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Okay, so maybe it doesn't always happen. Or maybe this one is the exception? Who knows.

Comment: Hmmm interesting, I can look at special casing this when the question it also deleted, will take a look Monday.