# Why are accepted answers immune from Flagging link-only answers as Not an Answer?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, answer-quality, link-only-answers

Let's assume you agree with the [yoda's corrective action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/148672) to a link-only-answer (#12) of the Faq Post [What is an acceptable answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer)?

> [A link only] answer must be improved as described above, else it will be
>   deleted. Downvote if link is tangential to the question. Write a new
>   answer with details and then flag as Not an Answer. Also flag if the
>   link is broken.

I think this is reasonable but I understand it's not strictly followed and people flag things without all the steps being followed and some mods will convert the answer to a comment.

But when I saw a case where this was being followed I thought it would be a no-brainer to flag it. I was really surprised when it was declined with

> Sadly accepted answers are the one exception to the "link-only-answer" rule.

I looked on meta and couldn't find anything that mentioned this.

Why does this rule exist?

And should it also extend to self-accepted answers?

Comment: I certainly don't know of, don't currently adhere to, nor have any plans to ever adhere to any rule of this nature.   NAA is NAA.

Comment: duplicate of [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: @gnat Why do you think that's a dupe? I was asking about why a mod wouldn't delete an *accepted* link only answer. [Image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ucHDV.png)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter because per my reading, dupe fives quite a straightforward guidance that nowadays, it is expected of mods to delete, no matter accepted or what: "let me be clear: **this sort of response is *not* an answer**. If you see this, flag it. Moderators, if you see it flagged, *delete it*..."

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ok, Kev asked me to chime in here, but before I get started let's have a quick sanity check:

**Moderators can delete any post at any time at their own discretion.** Moderators are expected to exercise discretion when doing so, but ultimately the choice and the responsibility is theirs. Your flag does not place any additional responsibility upon the responding moderator's shoulders, nor give him a mandate to do something he otherwise would not. He alone will answer for his actions, and therefore if he does not feel an action is justified he has the ability and indeed the duty to decline the flag requesting it.

**When flagging, your success rate is determined by your ability to clearly communicate what action should be taken and why.** Most of the time, the work is pretty much already done - a question is *visibly* non-constructive, an answer is *obviously* not an answer, and you need only pick the flag option that corresponds to this. Sometimes, more explanation is needed.

<sup>*>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>end of sanity (check)*</sup>

---

### So let's talk about "not an answer":

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

For a moderator, this presents one of four action items:

1. Convert to an edit (if posted by the OP)
2. Convert to a comment (if intended to address some issue with another post)
3. Delete
4. Nothing

Which one of these is appropriate should be obvious from the context:

- Clarifications and additions to the question should be converted to edits.
- *Useful* commentary on other posts should be converted to comments. This includes answers that ask the OP for additional information, etc.
- Follow-up questions, "I too have this problem", off-topic / non-constructive commentary directed at other posts or their authors, and random bits of noise and fluff that make no effort to *answer the question* should be deleted.
- Things that are legitimately answering the question (even if incorrect) should be ignored.

[image: not an answer]

This is pretty visibly *not* an answer. It's also not an edit, and not a useful comment. So the remaining action is ol' #3, *delete.* Moderators can and do make these decisions very quickly - there are a *lot* of non-answers posted and flagged.

#### And then there are link-only answers

[image: A link-only answer]

I'm not going to re-hash all of the problems with them, from spam to broken links - we're all plenty familiar with the pain they cause. But here's the thing: sometimes, they *do* answer the question - because it's a bad question, or because it's just a really useful link. The problems remain, but strictly-speaking *'not an answer' no longer applies*.

Of course, the *best* outcome for a useful link-only answer isn't **deletion** in any case - it's **editing!** If someone, particularly the author, comes back and expands that link into something that directly addresses the problem and uses the link *as a reference*... Now you have an answered question without the problems of bare links.

**Straight-up deletion** is problematic *when the link is actually useful* - at best, you're encouraging someone else to re-post it with more of an introduction; at worst, you're turning an answered question into an unanswered question for the sake of Purity.

And **converting them to comments** is really sort of an abuse of comments. *Most* not-an-answers make lousy, worthless comments too - spam in a comment isn't a whole lot better than spam in an answer. And for those useful link-only answers, you're just turning something that *could* be improved (anyone can suggest a fix for a broken link in an answer) into a [disposable "Post-It note"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) that can't ever be fixed and will probably just end up deleted. I've *seen* questions, sitting around for months or years, nominally unanswered but in reality answered by comments... Congratulations, you've recreated a worse PHPBB *within* Stack Overflow.

I should also note that we've been improving the filter right along to block more and more link-only answers *before they're even posted* - this too is preferable to deletion, since the author can easily expand the answer and re-post. Of course, it does nothing for older answers. We're also working on tools to fix broken links. In *answers*...

### So what's a mod to do?

In most cases, a link-only answer is just going to be deleted. Let's face it: the moderators on Stack Overflow really don't have time to be doing in-depth analysis on the benefits of a flagged answer that looks lazy. But to avoid the problems I outline above, I've recommended a bit of caution in the past:

> as a sanity-check next time: no matter how lazy an answer is, if there isn't a better (objectively more detailed, comprehensive, or - this is key - useful to the asker) answer, deleting it / converting it doesn't really accomplish anything. Its acceptance may indeed indicate the question itself isn't very good, but if so you should focus on the question.

In the particular instance you cite, the *question itself* wasn't a good question; indeed, it was a shopping question. Link-only answers are common on shopping questions - unless you can preserve other, more educational answers by cleaning them up, it makes more sense to just *close and/or delete the question*. This has now been done. Fixating on the answer here (which was +10 and accepted, but since it was posted by the asker acceptance doesn't mean a lot) means not seeing the forest for the trees.

But even decent questions sometimes get link-only answers, and if there's only *one useful answer*, deleting it to achieve purity accomplishes nothing.

Remember: moderators are doing this *quickly* - snap decisions to delete, convert, or leave it be. There may be some complicated reason why a lone, up-voted, accepted answer should be removed, but chances are the moderator just sees a lone, up-voted, accepted answer. Which brings me to...

### So what should *I* do?

There's a lot you can do, actually...

- If you're familiar with the subject, you can make a quick edit: quote or paraphrase the relevant portion of the article, copy and attribute the relevant bit of code, or even just write a small introductory paragraph.
- Leave a comment for the author, asking him to expand his answer a bit. Link to that FAQ... Maybe throw in a down-vote.
- Vote to close and/or flag the question if a poor question is leading to poor answers.
- Flag as "not an answer"
- If the answer *looks* like it's been useful, but really just needs to go, flag with a custom reason and explain briefly why:

  > "Cleaning up poor answers to borderline question so the good ones can remain"
  >   "Link is broken and cannot be fixed"
  >   "Link contained a live bobcat"
  >   etc.

Comment: *In the particular instance you cite, the question itself wasn't a good question* I'm sorry I didn't make it clearer . The flag I was referring to was on  May 31 '12 at 20:57. This question isn't a shopping question. It has an alternative answer that came later that wasn't just link to documentation on an object

Comment: Ah... Yes, I was looking at the wrong flag then. In *that* case, a better answer exists, the author of the answer was advised (by the responding moderator) to improve it, and declined to do so. I've added the link to the other answer, and deleted the link-only answer. Nothing of value has been lost.

Comment: Nice balancing act there.  The distinction between moderator actions and user actions is *much* appreciated.

Comment: Post contained live bobcat, would not read again

Comment: _turning something that could be improved... into a disposable "Post-It note" that **can't ever be fixed**..._ how's that? Anyone can add a new answer extending the link provided in comments - if that's not a _fix_ then I don't know what is

Comment: @gnat: that's not really "fixing" the comment, that's using it as a reference when posting an answer. You can't fix a broken link. You can't even *see* the link if someone flags the comment and it's deleted. There's no revision history on comments. The message here for years now has been, **don't use comments for information you want to stick around.** Converting answers into comments when they aren't actual commentary violates this - and also sends the wrong message to the author / other readers: [that comments are a place for short answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136004/).

Comment: @Shog9 I see; your reasoning makes pretty good sense for short answers. However, I doubt that link-only answers qualify as such - first of all because these openly violate [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) instructions requiring: "...Always quote the most relevant part of an important link..." (section _Provide context for links_)

Comment: @gnat: then the question becomes, are you converting answers into comments because they should be comments, or are you doing it to "punish" the author somehow? Note that the system *automatically* converts very short answers to comments as a form of immediate feedback to the author... Does this "teaching" conversion still work if it happens a day later? How about a year? I'm skeptical. For new answers, the bar is much higher already - you can't post it at all unless you have at least 50 non-link characters. Making this higher, providing *immediate* feedback, is probably far more productive.

Comment: @Shog9 _immediate feedback_ hm interesting. What if answerer simply ignores my downvote and comment? Low quality content would then stay, making whole effort kind of futile wouldn't it. As for "punishment", it seems impossible-by-design since author has an option to edit and undelete their answer, right?

Comment: @gnat: no, authors cannot undelete their own posts if a moderator has deleted them (self-deleted and community-deleted posts can be undeleted). And unless a comment is left, they may not even realize the deletion/conversion has occurred. It's not entirely uncommon for users to end up answer-banned before they realize what they're doing wrong.

Comment: @Shog9 I know about mod-deleted restriction; here, I meant undeletion by flagging improved answer for moderator attention. In case if they don't even notice deletion/conversion, my point about _no-punishment_ stays, too - simply because it's not a punishment when "target person" is not even aware of it

Comment: If they aren't aware of it, @gnat, and the answer *isn't a comment* - then it accomplishes **nothing.** Apart from confusing the appropriate uses of answers and comments, and turning an editable answer into a static, disposable comment.

Comment: @Shog9 hm at least, this would bump the question, giving it more eyeballs and a new chance to get better answers, including (but not limited to) answers built on link that has been converted to comment. But OK let's pretend this is **nothing** - what else would you suggest for link-only answers? Downvote with comment would be great if answerer pays attention but what if they simply ignore this?

Comment: @gnat: I list five suggestions in this answer, starting with Edit and ending with Custom Flag. At some point, someone has to make a call as to whether an unimproved answer is so worthless that the question is better off without it - if you can't make that call (or can't write a good rationale for it to sway a moderator), then leave it for someone who can. I'm not against deleting these - I'm against *blindly* deleting them. We could easily write a *script* to destroy all link-only answers on the site - assuming there's value in having humans make that call, it's in their nuanced judgement.

Answer (score 14):

They're not, they can be deleted like anything else. That's a custom message a mod must have replied with.

There might be more reluctance to delete an accepted answer because we can't re-accept an answer, but there's no reason you shouldn't flag non-answers as Not an Answer; checkmark included. At best such an answer is a helpful comment (that is if it really isn't an answer, of course).

As Gilles says, do try and edit/answer if possible (unless other answers are already sufficient), ideally a question should be left with whatever helpful information was at the end of that link in a succinct answer somewhere.

Comment: No reason except the fear that a moderator is going to decline a perfectly valid flag.

Comment: If you fear the moderators, or if they decline a perfectly good flag, drag it to [metase] and post the link here.

Comment: @animuson declining a flag is pretty minor, and they can be dismissed as Helpful as well (which is really the default action).

Comment: I'm pretty sure re-accepting the answer is as simple as undeleting it again. Deleted accepted answers retain their checkmark, although it's not always visible, [which is a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125984/accepted-answers-to-deleted-questions-dont-have-a-checkmark).

Comment: @lunboks or accepting a different answer, which still works (at least I'm not aware of it not working)

Answer (score 12):

I don't see why the fact that an answer is accepted would change anything. I've never heard of such a rule either. If anything, seeing a link-only answer accepted makes me more prone to converting it to a comment¹ (or deleting it if it's redundant). An accepted answer makes the question less likely to draw attention, and is more of a loss the day the link break.

As usual, the best course of action is you see a link-only answer is to provide real content, either by editing the answer or by writing your own answer. If the answer is recent, leave a comment asking the poster to provide more information; link to [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). If this is not possible (because the link is already dead and you don't know what was behind it, or because there's no one available with enough subject knowledge to provide content), or if another answer makes the link-only answer redundant, go ahead and convert/delete/flag.

¹  <sub>Since this is a moderator-only action, flag as not an answer unless you're a moderator.</sub>

Comment: to _flag as not an answer_ is a risky advice: moderator dealing with your flag may disagree that link-only is eligible. I once had [6 flags in the row](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109383/165773 "'Was it a mistake to flag these answers?'") declined that way. Much safer option would be to use ["Other" flag with the appropriate explanation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jIt1i.jpg): it leaves less room for moderator to misinterpret your intent

Answer (score 3):

Link only answers should indeed be flagged. However when it's the *accepted* answer things are more tricky. If the accepted answer is "link only" and we opt to delete then:

- we are going against the wishes of the OP who clearly found whatever was at the other end of that link useful, so much so he/she accepted it
- we now have a question that doesn't have an accepted answer

We do of course delete link-only accepted answers:

- if the link is broken
- it's a link to another Stack Overflow question, in which case we'd close the question as a dupe

I'm hoping Shog will chip in here because there was some discussion amongst the mods and the community team about this particular scenario.

Comment: How about self answers?

Comment: If the answer is the *only* answer, it doesn't have an answer, but if there are other, valid answers, then technically it does have an answer.  I believe you meant it doesn't have an *accepted* answer, which, frankly, is something that while encouraged, is not necessary and primarily used for the gamification of the site and not really to help others.  After all, it indicates what worked *for the person who asked the question*, YMMV.

Comment: @casperOne just because a link only answer is the only answer, that doesn't make the question "not have an answer". It just means the link-only answer is a poor answer.

Comment: @jcolebrand What I meant was, if the answer is the only answer, and it's deleted/converted, then the question won't have an answer.

Comment: I see. Then in that case I stand by my original answer: "edit it so it's not invalid anymore"

Comment: @jcolebrand On a site with the traffic of SO, that's simply outside the responsibilities of the moderator.  As users, yes, that's what moderators should do, but SO mods rarely have the bandwidth to perform operations like this nor are they expected to.

Comment: Hence: It's not the responsibility of the moderator to make those changes, but the person flagging it. If you're going to flag it, you should first be editing it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Flagging link-only answers as "Other" with appropriate "canned" explanation turned out just safer for me.

Works like a charm - eg yesterday, when I [successfully flagged an accepted answer having two upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870226/code-to-send-sms-using-j2me/870259#870259).

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIt1i.jpg]

I also think that for blatant link-only answers moderators should dismiss *Not an answer* flags as helpful, but [for the reasons other than flag being technically correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134654/165773).

Comment: Declining isn't always a "bad" thing, it's often done in order to give across a message; if a post kinda sucks but it isn't actionable, a declined message is a (unfortunately extremely subtle) way to explain why X isn't actionable. Don't be afraid of declined flags, they're pretty uncommon

Comment: @BenBrocka I don't know, guidance on declining flags in [SE Mod Newsletter](http://moderator.stackexchange.com/2011/09/september-2011-newsletter/) looks pretty straightforward to me: **"...Users are asked to flag posts to help keep the city street clean. Even if you feel the flag was not _technically_ correct, you don’t want to continually send the message that their help is no longer wanted. That is not what the feature is about..."**

Comment: Also note it could just be you got a moderator like casperOne whom agrees with the flag. It could have turned out differently if you had gotten one that would have declined.

Comment: @animuson yup, the whole bunch of MSO questions tagged [not-an-answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/not-an-answer) makes me feel like using it for link-only answers is like russian roulette. It gets OK or breaks pretty randomly

Comment: @gnat "don't continually send the message" is not the same as "never ever decline a single flag in your life", which is why declined flags are sort of uncommon, but when we decline one the reason usually is important.

Comment: @BenBrocka sure, when flag is declined by an important reason, or even by isolated one-off mistake, I have no problems with that. The very Mod newsletter I referred, clearly instructs to decline "unhelpful or noise" flags

Comment: Hm, at some point I should probably start reading the SE Mod Newsletter...