# Should link-only accepted answers be deleted?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, quality, vote-to-delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are accepted answers immune from Flagging link-only answers as Not an Answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135920/why-are-accepted-answers-immune-from-flagging-link-only-answers-as-not-an-answer)

I've flagged my fair share of link-only or link-plus-a-few-words answers, and most (or all) of them have been deleted.

Recently I discovered and flagged such an answer that happened to be the accepted answer. The flag was declined because the answer was the accepted answer.

Should standards such as not posting links without a real answer apply to answers that have been accepted?

Comment: Was it also the only answer? Perhaps the only upvoted answer even?

Comment: No. There are several answers (including the accepted answer) with a score of 1, and one answer with a score of 7