# How should answers containing just a link be flagged?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer, link-only-answers

I flagged an answer as not an answer because it contained just a link (or a little more than a link), and my flag was rejected because, "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer."

[image: screenshot]

I was not flagging it because it was technically inaccurate, or because it was wrong. I flagged it because it was a little more than a link, and the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) says:

> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are …
>
> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - "thanks!" or "me too!" responses
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - **barely more than a link to an external site**
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

In which way should an answer containing just a little more than a link, or two, be flagged?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I declined that flag originally it seems like a fair enough answer pointing the OP in the direction of the PHP docs - which, lets face it, aren't going to go away. We don't automatically delete every link only answer, see Shogs answer here about link only answers:

> [Why are accepted answers immune from Flagging link-only answers as Not an Answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136026/419)

The PHP docs are a decent reliable source.

This flag was handled via the flag summary report (where we just see the flagged post and act on it) and on a heavy flag day you don't always have time to open the full question to then do a deeper analysis.

Upon reviewing the second flag I revisited the question properly and to be honest it turns out that it was just junk so I deleted it - and that is why the other user who flagged the answer got a "helpful" mark.

Comment: Apart from accepted answers, is it better to flag the answer as not an answer, or use a custom flag?

Comment: @kiamlaluno 98% of the time I'd just bin link only answers. But, it depends on context. If it's the only answer and it looks correct, or it's a link to a reliable and notable source and is directly answering the question and is the best of a bad lot then it might be allowed to live. But it may be (as in this case) that the question is junk and needs to go instead.

Comment: @kiamlaluno NAA helps us more, because if we look at the link and think it would be able to be turned into a comment, the NAA flag makes the workflow easier for us.  Unless there's something about the content on the other end of the link that warrants a custom message (because we wouldn't just turn it into a comment), NAA helps us the most if you're just reporting link-only answers.