# Should accepted answers be convertable to comments?

Tags: discussion, convert-to-comment

I answered [this (closed) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12275805/102441) recently. I posted what was admittedly a short answer:

> I think you want [`stripslashes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

However, that was essentially all the asker (thought they) needed, and I believe they accepted it.

---

I came back earlier to see that answer had been converted to a comment. I don't have any complaint about this, but if seems a little odd for this to happen to an accepted answer. Does it make sense for this to happen? Is a question with no accepted answer better than a question with an accepted but brief answer?

Comment: To make it more of a complete answer, you could have added the reason why `stripslashes` is the answer they were looking for. Short answers with a single link can be converted automatically to comments.

Comment: Does the last line of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12275878/61305) have any truth to it? He didn't include any context but I'd guess that if there is an issue with the answer you proposed it's probably better off not being the accepted answer (in addition to the other more generic reasons).

Comment: @AaronBertrand: The answer does what the asker asked for. Whether he should be asking for it in the first place is another problem. For what he (initially) wanted to do, `stripslashes` is the way to do it.

Comment: @Eric ok, but you didn't answer my question, which I think is relevant.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I don't think the last line is meaningful. In what context should you not use it? If for whatever reason you need to evaluate character escape sequences in a string, then `stripslashes` is without a doubt what you want to use.

Comment: @Eric I don't know, I don't use PHP. I would ask him for more context. However I doubt he would say that just to blaspheme other answers.

Comment: Related: [Why are accepted answers immune from Flagging link-only answers as Not an Answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135920/why-are-accepted-answers-immune-from-flagging-link-only-answers-as-not-an-answer)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Having accepted an answer should have **no** bearing on the 'convert to comment' functionality.

If the post is not an answer, it should be converted to a comment (as appropriate). You can argue whether the answer should have converted to a comment in the first place, but 'accepting' that answer should not be a means of stopping that process. That would, in essence, be locking out a vital piece of functionality.

Comment: This seemingly contradicts another behavior exhibited by accepted answers - namely, the author's inability to delete them. I would argue that if an answer should be convertible to a comment, it should also be deletable.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It's a different issue. The basic philosophy of deleting content is that once you post something to SE, it becomes part of the collection and no longer belongs exclusively to you. Still, we let people remove their own content as long as it doesn't take away from or affect the contribution of others (e.g. can't delete questions that have answers, etc). An author having accepted your answer pushes your content more towards that *"part of the collective contribution"* side of that equation.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Not really the same thing, self deletions of good content are generally discouraged, the other example being askers not being able to delete their questions if there are upvoted answers.

Comment: @RobertCartaino There is still an inconsistency: once an accepted answer gets "demoted" to a comment, the author can delete what used to be "part of the collective contribution", because the "deletion of accepted answer" lock no longer applies.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Converting a post to a comment is a moderation issue correcting something that was posted incorrectly (assuming they made the correct call), so there's nothing inconsistent about it. A user having accepted the incorrectly-posted answer does make the location of the post any more correct, if it should have been a comment in the first place.

Comment: I agree, but at face value [Shog9 disagrees with you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135920/140951).