# What happens to the accepted answer when a question is deleted?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

If a question has an accepted answer and the question is deleted, what happens to the accepted answer and with the reputation coming from accepting that answer?

More specifically:

1. Is the accept sign automatically removed when a question is deleted?
2. It is known that reputation for answers [with score at least 3 and visible for at least 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13762/do-you-lose-the-reputation-points-you-acquired-from-a-question-if-when-it-is-d#150096) is kept after the deletion. Does this include the +15 reputation point for accepted answer, or are these 15 reputation points removed on deletion regardless of the age of the answer (even if the score is ⩾ 3)?

This came up in a discussion in chat (moved from comments on a per-site-meta). Since it was not that easy to find examples of such posts, asking here seemed a better solution than experimenting by looking for posts, deleting and undeleting them, checking reputation, etc.

I found this related question: [Accepted answers to deleted questions don't have a checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125984). However, no definitive answer was posted there, only a few comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1. Is the accept sign automatically removed when a question is deleted?

As @quid notes in the comments, new deletions do remove the accept sign. It used to be different before 2012, when interestingly, [the deletion causes the accepted answer to not show up at the top anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdMyx.png).

> 2. Does this include the +15 reputation point for accepted answer, or are these 15 reputation points removed on deletion regardless of the age of the answer?

The +15 points don't influence the +3 score needed (score and acceptance are two independent things). You'll keep the reputation from being the accepted answer if and only if you keep the reputation from the upvotes.

Comment: Sorry if my post was unclear. I meant in the second part: If an answer fulfills the conditions for keeping the reputation (i.e., score at least 3 and visible for 60 days), will only the reputation from the upvotes be kept, or does the user keep also +15?

Comment: BTW is there some trick how regular users could find deleted posts with accepted answer, or were you able to find such posts only using moderator superpowers?

Comment: Yep, that's a moderator ability: searching for `deleted:1 isaccepted:1`. I'll see if I can find some examples from my own past on Stack Overflow and show some reputation changes to prove the second part.

Comment: I couldn't find any, but [the question you linked to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125984/295232) shows at least that the reputation is kept for a high-scoring answer.

Comment: @Martin If an answer qualifies for reputation retention on the basis of score and non-deleted age, *all* reputation changes as a result of that answer are kept, *regardless* of where they originated from (votes, accepts, bounties, etc.)

Comment: Re 1. That's false. It is removed (since October 2012 I think). Old instances were  kept though it seems. Undeletion restores it though. If somebody tests and to avoid confusion : after the delete, **refresh** the page (the check is still shown otherwise)

Comment: @quid I should've noticed that the answers in my search results were all 8 years old ... thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I will add that this was discussed a bit in [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/93523/discussion-on-answer-by-lord-farin-can-we-please-stop-closing-and-deleting-old-p?tab=stars).